# Daily anacron mails with failure

Tags: flash, anacron

I'm receiving a daily mail from my Ubuntu with the current contents:

```
/etc/cron.daily/update-notifier-common:
Fetch:1 http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe [291 B]
Error:1 http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe
  404  Not Found
E: File https://freefr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/corefonts/the
+fonts/final/andale32.exe couldn't be fetched  404  Not Found

E: Download Failed
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading
+http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: processing...
```

This started a while back and I haven't figured out what to do. I tried:

```
sudo chown -R _apt:root /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/
sudo rm /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/*.FAILED
sudo apt install --reinstall update-notifier-common
```

I don't know if the email was a bit different in the past, but problem has always been the andale32.exe. Actually, after this I started to get mails with errors about flashplugin also in addition to just errors about andale32

What can I do? These emails fill my gmail.

ps. I tried to translate the email into English, as I receive the Finnish translation of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [this bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1607535). One way to fix it is to download `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` [from Debian](https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/ttf-mscorefonts-installer/download) and install that package.

Comment: If I install the package manually, will apt-get upgrade function normally in the future?

Comment: @Ville: I think so. Worth a shot.